# Why should version numbers not be pinned in a Pipfile?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I'm looking into using pipenv and in the docs here
https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#importing-from-requirements-txt

it says (emphasis mine)

> Note, that when importing a requirements file, they often have version
> numbers pinned, which you likely **won’t want**

Why is this?

I understand that the Pipfile.lock file will store the specific versions and hashes of the dependencies I install but don't I want to be able to see the specific versions of what is installed in Pipfile? (The same way I do when I use a requirements.txt?)

Comment: That URL is now flagged by Firefox "Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The docs are quite opinionated on the likely reason you have pinned versions on your requirements file: it probably came from `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Of course you'll want to specify some or all version ranges in your `Pipfile`, it's just that many people have them pinned in the `requirements.txt` because they used to treat it like a kind of `Pipfile.lock`, specifying versions of packages that aren't even direct dependencies. Naturally, if you didn't follow this practice, you don't have to worry about that warning.

This is very likely the result of Kenneth Reitz (Pipenv creator) himself doing that previously, as mentioned in his blog post [A Better Pip Workflow](https://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/a-better-pip-workflow). Clarification on this matter was already asked and answered by him in the official [repository](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/635).

**UPDATE JUNE, 2018**

That message used to be printed as a warning by the `pipenv` command as well, but it has been replaced with

```
requirements.txt found, instead of Pipfile! Converting…
Warning: Your Pipfile now contains pinned versions, if your requirements.txt did.
We recommend updating your Pipfile to specify the "*" version, instead.
```

A little bit more friendly, but I think it's still implicitly saying that pinning versions on Pipfile is not ideal, which is not true. It's perfectly fine.

Comment: Not only fine, but I think it is necessary. I am working without pinned versions in the `Pipfile` at the moment, and every time I do a `pipenv lock` (every couple of days) I end up having lots of changes in my `Pipfile.lock`, which is confusing and does not allow me to understand what is going on. I will move now to a pinned `Pipfile` (using the versions in the latest `Pipfile.lock`), and from now I hope I will be more in control of what is ultimately going to be installed.

Comment: This is something I don't get as well. Why are versions not pinned in Pipfile? Also, is there a way to pin them automatically instead of having to write them one by one ?

Comment: @wtfzambo I don't pin every dependency because I do want to update some of them when I run `pipenv lock` once in a while.

Comment: I prefer to pin all versions so I can know a bug was not introduced by dependencies upgrade, I don't like to have dependencies updated randomly, I like to upgrade one by one after checking their change log/release notes.

Comment: Specifying `"*"` in the Pipfile for any remotely serious project is a terrible idea. You should at the very least pin the major version (e.g. `>=1.2.3, <2.0.0`) to avoid unexpected breakage and still allow easily getting minor updates without having to change the pin each time. Poetry is much better in this regard, because by default when you do `poetry add package`, it pins it to the current latest version, like `^1.2.3` (which is equivalent to the previous expression of `>= 1.2.3, <2.0.0`).

Comment: Unless you're managing dependencies and want to re-lock your packages, most people are better served by installing exactly what's on Pipefile.lock anyway, in which case having "*" on the Pipefile doesn't make a difference. That said, I do think it's good practice to pin at least the major too - I only don't when I'm sure I have the tooling in place to allow me not to.

Comment: The python community is utterly reckless with version "*".  In large popular projects it can (and definitely has) cause(d) cascades of breakage.  Production dependencies can be pinned, but their transitive dependencies often aren't unfortunately.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure what the case was previously, however, [the latest documentation](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#specifying-versions-of-a-package) says that you can specify the version number for a package when you install it, like this:

```
pipenv install requests==2.13.0
```

This will also update the package in your `Pipfile` to include the version number, which looks like this:

```
requests = "==2.13.0"
```

You can do this for each of the packages you want to specify version numbers for—including if you've previously installed them.

I think you may be able to manually edit your `Pipfile` to do this, although I'm not sure if that'd be correct.

Comment: Yes manually editing the Pipfile is ok but one should not touch the Pipfile.lock file. Pipline.lock file is not meant to be touched. Once we edit the Pipfile we can delete the Pipfile.lock and  run ```pipenv install``` to re-genarate the file

Answer (score 4):

> don't I want to be able to see the specific versions of what is installed in the Pipfile?

The lock file is for tracking what is actually installed, and is the key to generating deterministic builds. Pipfile.lock is intended to be committed to a project along with the Pipfile. There is also the view that an ideal workflow is use "*pipenv lock* to compile your dependencies on your development environment and deploy the compiled Pipfile.lock to all of your production environments for reproducible builds."

Some versions you will want to specify in Pipfile. For example, all versions of Django below a certain major version is likely a good idea.

Also understand that as of now, pipenv is still under active development, so some of these ideas are still being worked out. It's possible there could be some changes.